# How to update all rows with column = to value except 1, then update that one to another value?

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I have a MySQL OFFERS table with an OID, PID and STATUS. STATUS has 3 ENUM values. O A C. (Open, Accepted, Closed). It looks like this:

```
+---------+-------------+--------+
|   oid   |    pid      | status |
+---------+-------------+--------+
|    1    |     1       |    o   |
|    2    |     1       |    o   |
|    3    |     1       |    o   |
|    4    |     2       |    o   |
+---------+-------------+--------+
```

All offers are open.
When a user wants to accept an offer, they click a button, which sends the post ID (PID) and the offer ID (OID) to the php file which does the UPDATE statement to the database. I want the statement to update the table to look like this:

```
+---------+-------------+--------+
|   oid   |    pid      | status |
+---------+-------------+--------+
|    1    |     1       |    a   |
|    2    |     1       |    c   |
|    3    |     1       |    c   |
|    4    |     2       |    o   |
+---------+-------------+--------+
```

**Psudo-PHP-MySQLI statement:**

```
UPDATE offers 
SET status='c' 
WHERE pid = $_POST['pid'], except WHERE oid = $_POST['oid']
```

but also SET status='a' WHERE oid = $_POST['oid']
I am new to PHP and MySQLi so I dont know how to structure all of the statements. Is this kind of statement even possible? I know to use prepared statements, but I am just adding the values in here just for simplicity. Thanks!

Comment: @Dharman Read the last sentence: "I know to use prepared statements"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `CASE` to specify different values to assign depending on a condition.

```
UPDATE offers
SET status = 
    CASE oid
        WHEN $_POST['oid'] THEN 'a'
        ELSE 'c'
    END
WHERE pid = $_POST['pid']
```

Comment: yeah, it didnt update quick enough. i deleted the comment. thanks again man!